# How should I fill out a module declaration file for a JS library with Typescript-incompatible inheritance practices?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm filling out a module declaration of a 3rd-party JS library, and the library contains subclasses that (by Typescript's reckoning) incompatibly override methods from a parent class. There are many instances of this, but a simple example is the following:

Base class:

```
class Entity {
  ...

  /**
  * Test whether a given User has permission to perform some action on this Entity
  * @param {User} user           The User requesting creation
  * @param {string} action       The attempted action
  * @return {boolean}            Does the User have permission?
  */
  can(user, action) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Subclass:

```
class User extends Entity {
  ...

  /**
   * Test whether the User is able to perform a certain permission action. Game Master users are always allowed to
   * perform every action, regardless of permissions.
   *
   * @param {string} permission     The action to test
   * @return {boolean}              Does the user have the ability to perform this action?
   */
   can(permission) {
     ...
   }
}
```

How can I faithfully represent overridden methods like the above without tsc pointing out the obvious? Or am I going to have to "lie" in some way and misrepresent the relationship between `Entity` and `User`?

Comment: From the code presented, `User` ***isn't*** a subclass of `Entity`...

Comment: @spender Thanks, fixed. I hand-typed-out the truncated code for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a type that erases the `can` property from the base `Entity` type, then assign `Entity` to a variable of that type.

Now you can create a new class derived from this "class"-reference variable.

This breaks polymorphism (as did the original developer). It's awful. Don't do this. Bite the bullet and refactor your mess.

```
class Entity {
    can(user: string, action: string) {
        console.log(user, action)
    }
}

type PartialEntity = new () => { [P in Exclude<keyof Entity, 'can'>]: Entity[P] }

const EntityNoCan: PartialEntity = Entity;

class User extends EntityNoCan {
    can(permission: number) {
        console.log(permission)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you recommend I refactor "my mess?" Or are you invoking the royal "you?"

Comment: Well, it seems you've inherited a design that abuses the lax nature of JavaScript inheritance. By taking this approach, the created objects violate Liskov substitution principle, defeating the whole point of inheritance. It's a flaw in the underlying design that, were it me, I'd take a detour to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a `// @ts-ignore` is really the only option here. The other proposed solution isn't applicable to type declarations.